Is there a way to change cache controls to images coming from a CDN in Nextjs?
I have a Nextjs (14.2.4) deployed on vercel where 99% of my images are stored locally except the user images that are stored and served from BunnyCDN.
The local images I'm fine with a long cache max-age time, since that will very rarely be modified.
However, the images coming from the CDN have the following cache-control: cache-control: public, max-age=2592000, must-revalidate
That is way too big time considering users may want to update their picture. I tried to change the cache settings in BunnyCDN but it is being ignored by Next as images are being served from _next/image so I guess the cache settings come from there?
I don't want to modify the cache for every image because the locally stored images are fine with the default one. Is it possible in Nextjs to change the max-age only for the pictures that comes from the CDN?
So far I tried to change the cache settings from BunnyCDN but it seems like the problem doesn't come from there as even manually removing CDN cache does not really update it on my app.
I also tried the following setting on next config file:
async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: 'https://my-site.b-cdn.net/:path*.webp',
                headers: [
                    { key: 'Cache-Control', value: 'public, max-age=3600' },
                ],
            },
        ]
    }

But I got the following error:
`source` does not start with / for route {"source":"https://my-site.b-cdn.net/:path*.webp","headers":[{"key":"Cache-Control","value":"public, max-age=3600"}]}

So I guess this would only work for local images? Not sure and I didn't find docs very helpful
